# How to open dataframe stored in pickle in S3 on AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pickle

I'm trying to load a dataframe file stored in pickle, and edit the dataframe. I'm opening in linux ubuntu AWS server, loading from S3. I could open by using pd.read_pickle in my environment, but that doesn't seem possibly when loading from S3

I can load and save from and to CSV, and I can also save to pickle, but I can't find a solution to load a pickle file. I tried copying almost every advice i could get on stackoverflow, but none seemed to work.

First, I tried

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import io

s3=boto3.client('s3')
session = boto3.session.Session()
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket = 'mybucket', Key = 'inputfile.pkl')

response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key= inputfile)

body_string = response['Body'].read()
pickled = pickle.dumps(body_string)
df=pd.read_pickle(pickled) #embedded null type error
```

I also tried

```
import pickle
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_pickle = pickle.loads(s3.Bucket('bucket').Object('inputfile').get()['Body'].read())

df = pd.read_pickle(my_pickle) # with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
                                   # return pkl.load(fh) error
```

Below is the method i used to save to pickle file

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3")
s3=boto3.client('s3')

obj = s3.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = inputfile)

df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'],index_col = False, low_memory = False)

pickle_buffer = io.BytesIO()

df.to_pickle(outputfile) 

s3_resource.Object(bucket, outputfile).put(Body = open(outputfile, 'rb'))
```

I expect to get a df that i can work on, as I get from df = pd.read_pickle() or df = pd.read_csv()